# Problema con pagina responsive en maps bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Tengo un pequeño problema al momento de realizar el responsive , para mostrar la ubicación de un mapa en bootstrap, como adjunto en la imagen así me visualiza en un teléfono de resolución 320*480, en resoluciones posteriores no existe inconveniente alguno, el problema solo reside al visualizar en dispositivos celulares, y el cliente me pide que lo visualice de la manera correcta en todas las resoluciones posibles si alguien me podría ayudar para ver que estoy realizado de manera errónea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../img/web/ico_dientes_sanos.ico">

  <title>Clínica Dental Equilibrium</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- navbar -->

  <div class="navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <nav class="container navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light text-center">
      <img src="../../img/web/ico_dientes_sanos.ico" width="30" height="30" alt="" loading="lazy">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#cita">Cita</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#servicios">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonios">Sonrisas</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#localizanos">Localízanos</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

 

  <!-- localizacion -->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <!--Google map-->
      <!--Section: Contact v.1-->
      <section class="section pb-5" id="localizanos">
        <!--Section heading-->
        <h2 class="section-heading h1 pt-4">Contáctenos</h2>
        <!--Section description-->
        <p class="section-description pb-4">Si deseas más información te invitamos a enviarnos un correo a la siguiente dirección de correo electrónico <a href="mailto:clinicaequilibrium@outlook.cl">clinicaequilibrium@outlook.cl.</a> donde resolveremos todas tus dudas y consultas.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
            <!--Form with header-->
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Header-->
                <div class="form-header blue accent-1">
                  <h3><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Write to us:</h3>
                </div>
                <p>We'll write rarely, but with only the best content.</p>
                <br>
                <!--Body-->
                <div class="md-form">
                  <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                  <input type="text" id="form-name" class="form-control">
                  <label for="form-name">Your name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="md-form">
                  <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                  <input type="text" id="form-email" class="form-control">
                  <label for="form-email">Your email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="md-form">
                  <i class="fas fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
                  <input type="text" id="form-Subject" class="form-control">
                  <label for="form-Subject">Subject</label>
                </div>
                <div class="md-form">
                  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt prefix grey-text"></i>
                  <textarea id="form-text" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                  <label for="form-text">Icon Prefix</label>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center mt-4">
                  <button class="btn btn-light-blue">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Form with header-->
          </div>
          <!--Grid column-->
          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <!--Google map-->
            <div id="map-container-google-11" class="z-depth-1-half map-container-6">
              <iframe
                src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d825.2495342706723!2d-70.7160187708199!3d-34.171965298785835!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9663458bc62723c3%3A0xedf120ae507f044b!2sClinica%20Equilibrium%20Rancagua!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sec!4v1610317986865!5m2!1ses-419!2sec"
                width="500" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false"
                tabindex="0"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Grid column-->
        </div>
      </section>
      <!--Section: Contact v.1-->
      <!--Google Maps-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- footer -->

  <div class="">
    <footer class="bg-dark text-center py-3">
      <a href="">Copyright © 
        <script>
          var f = new Date();
          document.write(f.getFullYear());
        </script>
        Clínica Equilibrium
      </a>
    </footer>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

De antemano le agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Simplemente agrega esta clase al iframe: `col-sm-12` y quita el `width:500` (Para que no depende de ello)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, efectivamente ese pequeño detalle era lo único que tenia que cambiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <!--Google map-->
  <!--Section: Contact v.1-->
  <section class="section pb-5" id="localizanos">
    <!--Section heading-->
    <h2 class="section-heading h1 pt-4">Contáctenos</h2>
    <!--Section description-->
    <p class="section-description pb-4">Si deseas más información te invitamos a enviarnos un correo a la siguiente dirección de correo electrónico <a href="mailto:clinicaequilibrium@outlook.cl">clinicaequilibrium@outlook.cl.</a> donde resolveremos todas tus dudas y consultas.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <!--Grid column-->
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
        <!--Form with header-->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <!--Header-->
            <div class="form-header blue accent-1">
              <h3><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Write to us:</h3>
            </div>
            <p>We'll write rarely, but with only the best content.</p>
            <br>
            <!--Body-->
            <div class="md-form">
              <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
              <input type="text" id="form-name" class="form-control">
              <label for="form-name">Your name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="md-form">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
              <input type="text" id="form-email" class="form-control">
              <label for="form-email">Your email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="md-form">
              <i class="fas fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
              <input type="text" id="form-Subject" class="form-control">
              <label for="form-Subject">Subject</label>
            </div>
            <div class="md-form">
              <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt prefix grey-text"></i>
              <textarea id="form-text" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
              <label for="form-text">Icon Prefix</label>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center mt-4">
              <button class="btn btn-light-blue">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Form with header-->
      </div>
      <!--Grid column-->
      <!--Grid column-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <!--Google map-->
        <div id="map-container-google-11" class="z-depth-1-half map-container-6">
          <iframe class="col-12 col-sm-12"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d825.2495342706723!2d-70.7160187708199!3d-34.171965298785835!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9663458bc62723c3%3A0xedf120ae507f044b!2sClinica%20Equilibrium%20Rancagua!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sec!4v1610317986865!5m2!1ses-419!2sec"
            height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false"
            tabindex="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Grid column-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--Section: Contact v.1-->
  <!--Google Maps-->
</div>
```

Gracias al aporte de Juan Rivera, efectivamente se pudo solucionar ese pequeño detalle que me presentaba problemas en la vista responsive en dispositivos móviles.